# deserializing an object with a generic list

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize an object, the type is populated but I am getting null for the `List<Sport>`. Any ideas?

My classes:

```
class Sports
{
    public MsgTypes type { get; set; }
    public List<Sport> Sport { get; set; }
}

class Sport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Import_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int Min_bet { get; set; }
    public int Max_bet { get; set; }
    public int Updated { get; set; }
    public string Feed_type { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

The command for deserialization:

```
Sports _sports = (Sports) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sports>(jsonObj);
```

This is my JSON object:

```
"{\"code\":0,\"type\":4,\"Sports\":[{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"1\",\"import_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Soccer\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"1\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194889\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"2\",\"import_id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"Tennis\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"3\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194771\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"3\",\"import_id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"Handball\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"6\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403152901\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"4\",\"import_id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"Ice Hockey\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"4\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403080245\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"7\",\"import_id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Basketball\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"2\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194830\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"8\",\"import_id\":\"23\",\"name\":\"Volleyball\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"5\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194591\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"9\",\"import_id\":\"12\",\"name\":\"Rugby\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"7\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194710\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"12\",\"import_id\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Motorsport\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"12\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403065699\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"13\",\"import_id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Baseball\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"13\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194834\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"14\",\"import_id\":\"16\",\"name\":\"American Football\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"14\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403143326\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}},{\"Sport\":{\"id\":\"16\",\"import_id\":\"34\",\"name\":\"Beach Volley\",\"active\":true,\"order\":\"16\",\"min_bet\":\"0\",\"max_bet\":\"0\",\"updated\":\"1403194417\",\"feed_type\":\"Betradar\",\"locale\":\"en_us\"}}]}"
```

Comment: Looks like this JSON is not valid.

Comment: I think your `List<Sport>` in `Sports` needs to be named `Sports`, not `Sport`

Comment: @ChrisMantie: a class Name cannot be the same as a property name inside this class ;) That sports class looks pretty weird at all. I would either expect some other entity to have a collection of <Sport>. What is Sports meant to mean?

Comment: @YoupTube Ah, indeed. Well, it needs to be `Sports`, so he'll have to change the class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more level of nesting and different class names. You should be able to deserialize to such structure:

```
class SportsParent
{
    //Code for MsgTypes was not provided so it is commented out
    public List<SportGroup> Sports { get; set; }
}

class SportGroup
{
    public SportItem Sport { get; set; }
}

class SportItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Import_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }    //need to be converted to bool instead of int
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public int Min_bet { get; set; }
    public int Max_bet { get; set; }
    public int Updated { get; set; }
    public string Feed_type { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize using such code:

```
SportsParent _sports = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SportsParent>(jsonObj);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it actually worked :) But I dont really get why the extra level of nesting is required. Would you be so kind to provide the explanation?

Comment: Trimmed version of your serialized json looks like this: {"Sports": [ {"Sport": {"id":"1",} } ] }. This means that you have an object, which has a list property named Sports (this is represented by SportsParent class and property Sports). Each item in an array is represented by {"Sport": {"id":"1",} }, which indicates a single property named Sport (in code that is class SportGroup), and actual data is inside that object (class SportItem). I hope that makes sense